# Implementing Custom bind issues

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement native bind functionality. However, when I try to test it out, I'm not getting the expected output.

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

```js
Function.prototype.myBind =  function(...args) {
    const self = this;
    return function() {
        return self.apply(this, args);
    }
};

function demo() {
  return {
    name: 'James Bond',
    printName: function (args) {
      console.log(this.name, args);
    }
  };
}


const test = {
  name: 'Aqua Man'
};

console.log(demo().printName.myBind(test)('2020'));
// expected
console.log(demo().printName.bind(test)('2020'));
```

Comment: What is the unexpected result? What is the expected output? Note, `this.name` references the `name` property of the `window`. Why is the built-in `Function.prototype.bind()` not being used?

Comment: @guest271314 I am trying to implement my own bind function. The expected result has been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind to argument like this:

```
Function.prototype.myBind =  function(binder) {
    const self = this;
    return function() {
        return self.apply(binder, arguments);
    }
};
```